# How Kafka broadcast to many Consumer Groups

Tags: apache-kafka

I am new to Kafka and I will appreciate very much clarification on the next case.

Kafka documentation says in the  paragraph "Consumer Position":

> "Our topic is divided into a set of totally ordered partitions, each
>   of which is consumed by one consumer at any given time."

Based on statement above if few Consumer Groups subscribed to a topic and Producer will publish message to particular partition within this topic then only one Consumer can pull the message.

The question is how broadcast to many Consumer Groups could happen if only one Consumer can pull particular message?

Answer (score 34):

Only one consumer in a `consumer group` can pull the message. But **all** `consumer groups` get the messages.

So if you want all your consumers to get the messages, assign them different `consumer groups`. Each message goes to every consumer group, but within a group, it goes to only one consumer.

Read the `Consumer` section [here](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did read about the consumer group concept. That is why I am confused with statement "one consumer per partition" that is constantly repeated through documentation without reference to consumer group. Especially if I read about partition offset. Multiple consumer groups per topic assumes multiple offsets per topic's partition. Isn't it?

Comment: Your statement "Only One consumer in a consuemr group can pull the message" is not exactly true. Each Partition can be consumed by only One Consumer. So, if there are multiple consumers in a Consumer Group, they can still consume from different partitions. That is the whole point of parallel consumption with Kafka

Comment: @gaganbm If we have many partitions and many consumer groups with only one consumer each of them how Kafka scales up when a. we add more consumer groups and the number of partitions is constant b.we add more consumer groups and we add more partitions? Is the scale up linear or sublinear? Thanks in advance

Comment: @java_geek The statement is exactly true, because a message is enqueued in just one partition, never in more than one partition. And therefore it follows from the behaviour, you described in your comment, that a message can be received only by one consumer in a consumer group.

Answer (score 28):

if there are 10 partitions for a topic and 3 consumer instances (C1,C2,C3 started in that order) all belonging to the same Consumer Group, we can have different consumption models that allow read parallelism as below

**Each consumer uses a single stream.**
 In this model, when C1 starts all 10 partitions of the topic are mapped to the same stream and C1 starts consuming from that stream. When C2 starts, Kafka rebalances the partitions between the two streams. So, each stream will be assigned to 5 partitions(depending on the rebalance algorithm it might also be 4 vs 6) and each consumer consumes from its stream. Similarly, when C3 starts, the partitions are again rebalanced between the 3 streams. Note that in this model, when consuming from a stream assigned to more than one partition, the order of messages will be jumbled between partitions.

**Each consumer uses more than one stream (say C1 uses 3, C2 uses 3 and C3 uses 4).** 
In this model, when C1 starts, all the 10 partitions are assigned to the 3 streams and C1 can consume from the 3 streams concurrently using multiple threads. When C2 starts, the partitions are rebalanced between the 6 streams and similarly when C3 starts, the partitions are rebalanced between the 10 streams. Each consumer can consume concurrently from multiple streams. Note that the number of streams and partitions here are equal. In case the number of streams exceed the partitions, some streams will not get any messages as they will not be assigned any partitions.

If there is another consumer group, the same process is applied to consumers within that consumer group

Comment: I don't know why this answer has not been accepted. This describes a very crucial aspect to understand partition/consumer relation in Kafka.

Comment: The moderators actually deleted my answer as I have posted a link to my article that describes this in much more detail. Its a pity, but thats how StackOverflow seems to work.

Comment: When I read the "Each consumer uses more than one stream" model, I wasn't clear. It wasn't wrong, just that it wasn't clear. I re-wrote it to myself like so:

Comment: When I read the second model above, it wasn't clear to me (not that it was wrong). =:) So I re-wrote it to myself stressing that 'Different consumers within the *same* consumer group cannot consume from the same partitions. Thus *rebalancing* is the act of assigning some collection of partitions that is exclusively dedicated to one consumer in a consumer group; and a different collection of partitions to exclusively serve the next consumer in the group; and so on. As mentioned, "the same process is applied to consumers within different consumer group". I hope this interpretation was correct.

Answer (score 17):

Generally there are 2 kinds of messaging patterns:

1. Shared queue:
   All consumers subscribe to one single message queue. Each consumer compete with each other and for each message, only one consumer will get it.
2. Publish-subscribe:
   Each message is broadcast to all consumers subscribed. So all consumers will get the same message.

Kafka supports both of them at the same time through the concept of consumer group.
Consumers in the same group follow the shared queue pattern. Only one consumer in a group can get the message.

Different consumer groups follow the publish-subscribe pattern. For each message, all consumer groups that subscribed to the topic will get a copy of the message.

A useful reference:
https://dzone.com/articles/dont-use-apache-kafka-consumer-groups-the-wrong-wa

Answer (score 4):

Good Question.[image]

Take a example i m having a topic called **complaint** having two partition **p1,p2**

now i m having two consumer group called **group1** having two consumer **c1** and **c2** and **group2** having consume **c3**

here i route messages from **p1** should go to **c1** and **p2** should go to **c2** and i subscribed another consumer called **c3** but that is in different group so here copy of the whole message is send to that consumer also