# How multiple consumer group consumers work across partition on the same topic in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

I was reading [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23136500/how-kafka-broadcast-to-many-consumer-groups) and many such blogs.

What I know:

Multiple consumers can run on a single partition when running multiple consumers with multiple consumer group id and only one consumer from a consumer group can consume at a given time from a partition.

My question is related to **multiple consumers** from **multiple consumer groups** consuming from the **same topic**:

1. What happens in the case of multiple consumers(different groups) consuming a single topic(eventually the same partition)?
2. Do they get the same data?
3. How offset is managed? Is it separate for each consumer?
4. (Might be opinion based) How do you or generally recommended way is to handle overlapping data across two consumers of a separate group operating on a single partition?

Edit:
"overlapping data": means two consumers of separate consumer groups operating on the same partition getting the same data.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Yes they get the same data. Kafka only stores one copy of the data in the topic partitions' commit log. If consumers are not in the same group then they can each get the same data using fetch requests from the clients' consumer library. The assignment of which partitions each group member will get is managed by the lead consumer of each group. The entire process in detailed steps is documented here https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/72378/understanding-kafka-consumer-partition-assignment.html
2. Offsets are "managed" by the consumers, but "stored" in a special __consumer_offsets topic on the Kafka brokers.
3. Offsets are stored for each `(consumer group, topic, partition)` tuple. This combination is also used as the key when publishing offsets to the __consumer_offsets topic so that log compaction can delete old unneeded offset commit messages and so that all offsets for the same `(consumer group, topic, partition)` tuple are stored in the same partition of the __consumer_offsets topic (which defaults to 50 partitions)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you suggest how to handle 4th question?

Comment: Can you explain what it means "overlapping data"?

Comment: If for the performance improvement I decided to use 2 consumers from the separate consumer group on one partition. So, if consumers of the separate consumer group get the same data how to handle this data redundancy and make sure each message is processed only once across two consumers?

Comment: If you want to have more consumers than partitions and still have performance enhancement and process only each message once, then you should increase the number of partitions in the topics so that there are at least as many partitions as consumers. Often topics are created with 2 times as many partitions needed to start, just so more consumers can be added later if needed without having to repartition the topic.

Answer (score 1):

1. Each consumer group gets every message from a subscribed topic.
2. Yes
3. Offset are stored by partition. For example let's say you have a topic with 2 partitions and a consumer group named cg made up of 2 consumers. In that case Kafka assigns each of the consumers one of the partitions. Then the consumers fetch the offset for the partition they were assigned to from Kafka (e.g. consumer 'asks' Kafka: "What is the offset for this topic for consumer group cg partition 1", or partition 2 for the other consumer). After getting the correct offset the consumer polls some Kafka broker for the next message in that partition.

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by overlapping data, can you clarify a bit or give an example?

Comment: If for the performance improvement I decided to use 2 consumers from the separate consumer group on one partition.
So, if consumers of the separate consumer group get the same data how to handle this data redundancy and make sure each message is processed only once across two consumers?

Comment: You won't get any performance improvement from using separate consumer groups since they all do exactly the same work. Like Hans Jespersen said, if you need to have a performant solution you should use a topic with a lot of partitions and have a lot of consumers (that make up a single consumer group). Also, by default Kafka has at least once delivery semantics meaning you might have duplicate messages even using a single consumer group. Just recently Kafka added an exactly once delivery feature, see https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#upgrade_11_exactly_once_semantics